# SQL VB6 - Showing all Entries in Datagrid while using UNION ALL and Left Join

Tags: sql, vb6, left-join, union-all

```
create table TBLGRN (Supplier varchar(100),
                     ProductID INT,
                     QTY Int,
                     VoucherNo long);

Create table TBLINV (CustomerName varchar(100),
                     ProductID Int,
                     Qty int,
                     Invoiceno Long);

insert into tblgrn 
(Supplier,ProductID,Qty,VoucherNo)
Values
('Supplier1','1','5','12345');

insert into tblgrn 
(Supplier,ProductID,Qty,VoucherNo)
Values
('Supplier1','2','3',NULL);

insert into tblinv
(CustomerName,ProductID,QTY,Invoiceno)
values
('Customer1','1','5','12345');

SELECT g.ProductID, g.Qty AS GRNQTY,
i.qty AS InvQty FROM tblgrn g LEFT JOIN tblinv i
on g.voucherno=i.invoiceno WHERE supplier='SUPPLIER1'
AND i.productid=g.productid GROUP BY g.productid, g.qty, i.qty;
```

Ok, so now i have edited and simplified my code which i have also tried it on SQLFiddle, here the link.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/682bac/4

I want the code to show all the data in the TBLGRN table while joining those entries that have a corresponding voucherno on the tblinv table. If there is no corresponding voucherno in the tblinv table then the voucherno should show as null. At the moment it is just showing productID 1 that have been sold. I would like to see items that have already been sold and the ones that have not been sold.

I hope this time i explained well.

Comment: Why are you left joining? Your wheres remove any rows that left join adds to what inner join would return. Indeed the data you want would be in rows added by left join, the ones from left join with nulls for the right table. Do you understand what left join does? Also why can't you use OR intead of UNION? PS Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: This question is much too broad. What are you actually asking for help with? The SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the productid where condition on the left join.  The reason is that the condition will never be satisfied when i.productid = null

```
SELECT g.ProductID
       , g.Qty AS GRNQTY
       , i.qty AS InvQty 
FROM tblgrn g 
     LEFT JOIN tblinv i on g.voucherno=i.invoiceno AND i.productid=g.productid
WHERE supplier='SUPPLIER1'
GROUP BY g.productid, g.qty, i.qty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, I think your joining keys are the VoucherNo to InvoiceNo and the ProductID. Note that in accounting perspective, voucher is different from an invoice, but nvm. Try this instead, note that I added two fields:

```
SELECT g.ProductID,
       g.Qty AS GrnQty,
       i.Qty AS InvQty,
       g.VoucherNo,
       i.InvoiceNo
FROM   TblGrn g
LEFT JOIN TblInv i
ON     g.VoucherNo = i.InvoiceNo
  AND  g.ProductID = i.ProductID
WHERE  g.Supplier = 'SUPPLIER1'
GROUP BY g.ProductID,
       g.Qty,
       i.Qty,
       g.VoucherNo,
       i.InvoiceNo;
```

Comment: Thank you mate, that is what i was looking for. Much appreciated.